# Angular 7 Routes with Resolvers don't load Components

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular7

I'm having an Angular 7 issue where a module's child components that have a resolver on the route don't load.

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
{
  path: 'Account',
  loadChildren: './account/account.module#AccountModule'
}
```

**account-routing.module.ts**

```
{
  path: 'Profile',
  component: ProfileComponent,
  resolve: {
    profile: ProfileResolver
  }
}
```

**profile.resolver.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class ProfileResolver implements Resolve<Profile> {

  constructor(private readonly accountService: AccountService) {
  }

  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<Profile> {
    return this.accountService.profile();
  }
}
```

**profile.component.ts**

```
@Component({
⋮
})
export class ProfileComponent implements OnInit {

  model: Profile;

  constructor(private readonly route: ActivatedRoute) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.model = this.route.snapshot.data['profile'] as Profile;
  }
}
```

**account.service.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class AccountService {

  constructor(protected readonly http: HttpClient) {
  }

  profile(): Observable<Profile> {
    return this.http.get<Profile>(`${environment.apiUrl}/Account/Profile`);
  }
}
```

The behavior is that, when navigating to `/Account/Profile`, the `ProfileResolver` is called, hits the server, and gets a 200 response with the `Profile` object (I can see it in the Network tab), and then... nothing. Neither the `constructor` or the `ngOnInit` method of `ProfileComponent` are called.

If I remove the `ProfileResolver` from the `AccountRoutingModule` and call the `AccountService` directly from the `ngOnInit` method, it works. But there are a number of template parse errors from the template while it waits for the response (which is the whole reason I want to use the `resolve`).

Is there something extra I need to do to make a resolver work with these modules?

This might also be the same issue as described here: [Angular Router don't load component with resolver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53028101/angular-router-dont-load-component-with-resolver)

**UPDATE**: I turned on `enableTracing` so I could see what is happening. Here is the output:

```
Router Event: NavigationStart
NavigationStart(id: 2, url: '/Account/Profile')
NavigationStart {id: 2, url: "/Account/Profile", navigationTrigger: "imperative", restoredState: null}

Router Event: RoutesRecognized
RoutesRecognized(id: 2, url: '/Account/Profile', urlAfterRedirects: '/Account/Profile', state: Route(url:'', path:'') { Route(url:'Account', path:'Account') { Route(url:'Profile', path:'Profile') }  } )
RoutesRecognized {id: 2, url: "/Account/Profile", urlAfterRedirects: "/Account/Profile", state: RouterStateSnapshot}

Router Event: GuardsCheckStart
GuardsCheckStart(id: 2, url: '/Account/Profile', urlAfterRedirects: '/Account/Profile', state: Route(url:'', path:'') { Route(url:'Account', path:'Account') { Route(url:'Profile', path:'Profile') }  } )
GuardsCheckStart {id: 2, url: "/Account/Profile", urlAfterRedirects: "/Account/Profile", state: RouterStateSnapshot}

Router Event: ChildActivationStart
ChildActivationStart(path: '')
ChildActivationStart {snapshot: ActivatedRouteSnapshot}

Router Event: ActivationStart
ActivationStart(path: 'Profile')
ActivationStart {snapshot: ActivatedRouteSnapshot}

Router Event: GuardsCheckEnd
GuardsCheckEnd(id: 2, url: '/Account/Profile', urlAfterRedirects: '/Account/Profile', state: Route(url:'', path:'') { Route(url:'Account', path:'Account') { Route(url:'Profile', path:'Profile') }  } , shouldActivate: true)
GuardsCheckEnd {id: 2, url: "/Account/Profile", urlAfterRedirects: "/Account/Profile", state: RouterStateSnapshot, shouldActivate: true}

Router Event: ResolveStart
ResolveStart(id: 2, url: '/Account/Profile', urlAfterRedirects: '/Account/Profile', state: Route(url:'', path:'') { Route(url:'Account', path:'Account') { Route(url:'Profile', path:'Profile') }  } )
ResolveStart {id: 2, url: "/Account/Profile", urlAfterRedirects: "/Account/Profile", state: RouterStateSnapshot}
```

So it looks like the `ResolveEnd` event is never firing. I found this issue: [Router's ActivatedRoute `data` returns empty {} if module is lazy](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/19420). It seems like it may be related but I'm not sure how I would implement that fix here.

Comment: are you getting any error?

Comment: @Chellappan Nope, no error at all. And the browser url doesn't ever change either. It's interesting that if I do a Guard with an Observable it works just fine - only breaks this way with a Resolver.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I consulted the [Routing & Navigation](https://angular.io/guide/router) guide again and changed my Resolver to look like it does there:

**profile.resolver.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class ProfileResolver implements Resolve<Profile> {

  constructor(private readonly accountService: AccountService) {
  }

  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<Profile> {
    return this.accountService.profile().pipe(
      take(1),
      map((profile: Profile) => profile));
  }
}
```

The key was adding the `take(1)`. Without this, the `ResolveEnd` event is never fired and the `Router` just hangs.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, I tried based on your example and issue solved.

Comment: Always check if your observable is completing. `take(1)` is a good case for completion. But do not forget that if the observable is sending no value, it will not terminate.

Answer (score 4):

I think you have to subscribe to the resolver promise

```
@Component({
⋮
})
export class ProfileComponent implements OnInit {

  model: Profile;

  constructor(private readonly route: ActivatedRoute) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.router.data.subscribe( (data) => { <== here 
      this.model = data as Profile  <== here
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried that before and it didn't work (by itself). But I tried it again with some tweaks and it's working now. I'll mark this as answer and put details in question update.

Comment: great, happy coding.

Comment: Actually, this wasn't the answer. I was able to get it working without any changes to the component. I'll add a separate answer with the final fix. But still upvoting this!